# Monit and file timestamp error. Related script does not start

Tags: python, sqlite, shell, timestamp, monit

*

> SUMMARY
>
> If Monit or Cron does not start your script, it could be a PATH issue.
>   See below.

*

---

I have 2 main files:

1. the first, **A.py**, is the main script in Python, that updates an sqlite database **db.sqlite** continously (it should never stop);
2. the second, **B.sh**, is a shell script, that - if needed - kills and restart the 1st script (it will be run under Monit pre-configured condition - see below)

Both files are executable:

- **A.py** first line `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- **B.sh** first line `#!/bin/sh`

Then:

```
chmod +x A.py
chmod +x B.sh
```

I configured Monit to check the timestamp of the **db.sqlite** file, and if the timestamp is greater than 1 minute (which implies that for some unknown reason the **A.py** updating function has stopped though python script may be still running - that's why I cannot check the **A.py** status), then it will run the **B.sh** shell script, which restart **A.py**.

All works well if I run the scripts by hand, in a shell terminal.

But under Monit it seems not to work.

I add the following in the Monit configuration file (then I check the syntax `sudo monit -t` and reload the configuration `sudo monit reload`):

```
check file db.sqlite with path /right_dir/db.sqlite
     if timestamp > 1 minute then exec "/right_dir/restart.sh"
```

The **monit.log** report:

```
error    : 'db.sqlite' timestamp for /right_dir/db.sqlite failed -- current timestamp is ...
info     : 'db.sqlite' exec: /right_dir/restart.sh
error    : 'db.sqlite' timestamp for /right_dir/db.sqlite failed -- current timestamp is ...
error    : 'db.sqlite' timestamp for /right_dir/db.sqlite failed -- current timestamp is ...
```

*and so on...*

I `ps aux|grep A.py` but the script is not running.

I really appreciate any help.

Thank you for your time,

gil

---

### UPDATE

I tried a simple file, with **cron** instead of **monit**: if I run the script on a terminal all work well. Cron does not.

FYI: I use Anaconda (Python suite)

File **A.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("OK")
import matplotlib # this do block
import math # this do not block
while True:
    pass
```

File **B.sh**:

```
/usr/bin/pkill -f A.py
nohup /right_path/A.py &
```

**Crontab**:

```
*/1 * * * * /right_path/B.sh
```

After crontab start I check `ps aux|grep A.py`.

This line does not block (*I see the process with ps aux*):

```
import math
```

This line blocks (*I do not see the process*):

```
import matplotlib
```

So the problem seems to be related to the module import (some work, some not).

May be a PATH/Env issue?

Any idea?

---

### SOLVED

It is a PATH problem.
Cron does not see the complete PATH, but only a minimal subset.
Just try for yourself: add to crontab (`crontab -e`) the following:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

and compare the output to the `env` command run in your terminal.
They are probably different.

The solution is to copy the complete PATH from your terminal and paste it as the second line of **B.sh** just like that (take it as an example, your situation may be slightly different):

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

# rest of the script
```

Thank to this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work